# Chronological Sorting in Excel

Tags: excel

I need to sort a column of data by date in Excel. The challenge is some rows show a single month (e.g. April 2013), and other show two months separated by a slash (May/June 2013). There is not much logic to which rows have the back-to-back months, so I can't do a simple find and replace. Can I use a formula or some other Excel trick to get all of the back-to-back months to fall into chronological order.

Essentially, I need a function that removes anything between a / and a number (the year).

The other challenge I am finding is that, when I create a function that gets close to the solution, the function column can't be sorted chronologically.

I am using Excel 2007

Comment: You can split doubles into singles, and sort by two columns. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create custom sort... To do custom sort please follow below steps:

```
Home Menu >> Click on Sort & Filter >> Click on Custom Sort
```

Now In Sort Popup window ...

```
1. Select Sort By Column 
2. Select Sort On 'Value'
3. Select Custom List
    a. In Custom List add below list in same define order (You can change format as per your requirements)
          Jan-13
          Jan/Feb-13
          Feb-13
          Feb/Mar-13
          Mar-13
          Mar/Apr-13
          Apr-13
          Apr/May-13
          May-13              
          May/Jun-13
          Jun-13
          Jun/Jul-13
          Jul-13
          Jul/Aug-13
          Aug-13
          Aug/Sep-13
          Sep-13
          Sep/Oct-13
          Oct-13
          Oct/Nov-13
          Nov-13
          Nov/Dec-13
          Dec-13
```